# Zend Framework 2: Trying to get a list of module controllers and actions

Tags: zend-framework2

Trying to get an array of module controllers and actions for an ACL module I am developing. Still learning the framework, and trying to pull the information from either an autoloader or somewhere that would have it stored from bootstrap. Trying to cut down on additional requests if not needed. Here is an example of what I need for a final output:

- Application (Module)

  - IndexController

    - ViewAction
    - EditAction
    - DeleteAction
- ZfcUser (Module)

  - UserController

    - IndexAction
    - LoginAction

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am not opposed to scraping the directories for the files and checking the classes for the methods, but I was hoping for a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any given request, you should likely only ever have one controller actually loaded into memory (unless you use things like forward()). The reason for this is that you will pull the specific controller instance routed to from the ControllerManager, giving you that one instance.

If you want a list of all controllers, you could introspect the ControllerManager service. Since that plugin manager implementation extends ServiceManager, you can call the method "getRegisteredServices()", which provices a list of service names by service type. From there, you could loop over each and retrieve each controller (as the service names may not have a 1:1 relationship with the class names).

That gets you controllers.

For the actions, that depends on the implementation. If the controller is an AbstractActionController implementation, use Reflection on the class to get a list of methods, and any method ending in "Action" will be an action. For the AbstractRestfulController implementation, this is also true, but you'll also have the methods getList, get, create, update, and delete. Finally, remember that a controller simply is any object that implements Zend\Stdlib\DispatchableInterface; as such, the idea of an "action" may not always be relevant. (As an example, I've built a number of "page" controllers and service endpoints that only define dispatch().)

Comment: I'll try using the getRegisteredServices method and see how it goes. Thank you for the help, it's much appreciated.

Comment: @weirophinney - How can you pull out the action name that is set in the AbstractRestfulController to compare that with an ACL? I need to lock down our app by not only controller, but action too. The action seems to get set to the request after calling the actual method. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this component in order to get what you want : Zend\Code,
here is an example that can help you to get started :

```
public function testGetAllRessources() {
    $sc = new DirectoryScanner();
    $sc->addDirectory('Path/to/Your/Module/src/Module/Controller/');
    $sc->addDirectory('Path/to/Your/SecondModule/src/SecondModule/Controller/');
    foreach ($sc->getClasses(true) as $classScanner) {
        $classname = $classScanner->getName();
        echo 'Controller: ' . $classname . PHP_EOL;
            foreach ($classScanner->getMethods(true) as $method) {
                if($this->endsWith($method->getName(),'Action')) {
                        echo 'Action: ' . $method->getName() . PHP_EOL;
                }
        }
    }
}

function endsWith($haystack, $needle) {
    $length = strlen($needle);
    if ($length == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return (substr($haystack, -$length) === $needle);
}
```